# Node uses ffmpeg to push streams with high latency and blurry images?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

### Realize ideas

- nodeJS gets the base64 data of the image
- Push to rtmp via ffmpeg pipe

### code

```js
const child_process = require('child_process')
let child = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-f', 'image2pipe',
  '-i', '-',
  '-vcodec', 'libx264',
  '-f', 'flv',
  'rtmp://127.0.0.1:56413/live/test'
]);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

child.on('close', (code, signal) => {
  console.log('ffmpeg', code, signal);
});


// image data write pipe
function writeImg (base64) {
  let imgData = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64')
  child.stdin.write(imgData)
}


// Simulate loop to get image data
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
  writeImg('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA........')
}
```

### question

- Screen delay is too high
- blurry screen

**I would like to ask if there is any way to optimize it, thank you**

Comment: If you use the command-line ffmpeg to create a video file from some images with those parameters, do you have the same output issues?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.